# I was trying to remove Thunderbird but I saw ubuntu-mate-dektop package was also being removed

Tags: package-management, 15.10, thunderbird, mate

I am running Ubuntu Mate 15.10 on my system. I was trying to remove Thunderbird using `sudo apt-get autoremove thunderbird` but then noticed that in the list of packages to be removed, there was also `ubuntu-mate-desktop`. Why does this happen? What will happen if that also gets removed? And, how do I only remove thunderbird?

Answer (score 3):

The safer way to remove/ uninstall a package is by using the command :

```
sudo apt-get purge thunderbird
```

The `autoremove` feature removes all the packages in the system that are not needed.

Hope it helps.